# How to pick video from google photos app?

Tags: android, video, gallery, android-gallery, google-photos

I am trying to pick video from google photos app but I am not getting the correct URI when trying to pick video that is stored in cloud of google photos.

Intent initialization

```
Intent pickVideoIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
                            pickVideoIntent.setType("video/*");
                            pickVideoIntent.addFlags(FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
                            pickVideoIntent.addFlags(FLAG_GRANT_PERSISTABLE_URI_PERMISSION);
                            startActivityForResult(pickVideoIntent, REQ_CODE_PICK_VIDEO);
```

In the onActivityResult

```
Uri selectedMediaUri = data.getData();
             if (selectedMediaUri.toString().contains("video")) {
                Uri uri = data.getData();
                String path = getPath(uri, getContext());
                uploadVideoFromUri(uri, path);
            }

public static String getPath(Uri uri, Context context)
    {
        String[] projection = { MediaStore.Video.Media.DATA };
        Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, null, null, null);
        if (cursor != null) {
            int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Video.Media.DATA);
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            return cursor.getString(column_index);
        } else
            return null;
    }
```

the resulted Uri is

```
content://com.google.android.apps.photos.contentprovider/0/2/mediakey%3A%2Flocal%253A8941afc5-97e6-437c-8387-b5591f3e1ede/ORIGINAL/NONE/video%2Fmpeg/2022128414
```

The result of getPath() is always null.

Comment: "The result of getPath() is always null" -- well, sure. There is no requirement for a `Uri` to respond to that query, and even if it does, the resulting value might not be useful. Use the `Uri` itself (e.g., hand it to ExoPlayer for playing the video). Also, please note that [`ACTION_PICK` does not take a MIME type and does expect a collection `Uri`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent#ACTION_PICK), so your approach leaves you at risk of compatibility problems on many devices.

Comment: Also action pick can do without those flags. Remove them as they do nothing and are only confusing for readers.